# Loading screen with react to improve UX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am little confused about loading data approach.
So i want to show loading screen on page load until all data is loaded, my approach is to make for each fetch method on this page a loading state. here I am using `redux` with thunk to dispatch `async` action.

actions-types:

```
export const IS_LOADING_SKILLS = "IS_LOADING_SKILLS";
export const SET_SKILLS = "SET_SKILLS";
export const IS_LOADING_INTRO = "IS_LOADING_INTRO";
export const SET_INTRO = "SET_INTRO";
```

actions:

```
import { SET_SKILLS, SET_INTRO,IS_LOADING_INTRO,IS_LOADING_SKILLS} from "./actions-type"

export const fetchSkills = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(isLoadingSkills(true));
    await api.get(url)
        .then(({ data }) => dispatch(setSkills(data)));
    dispatch(isLoadingSkills(false));
   }
}
export const fetchIntro = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(isLoadingIntro(true));
    await api.get(url)
        .then(({ data }) => dispatch(setIntro(data)));
    dispatch(isLoadingIntro(false));
   }
}

const setSkills = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: SET_SKILLS,
        payload: payload
    }
}
const setIntro = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: SET_INTRO,
        payload: payload
    }
}
const isLoadingSkills = (payload)=>{
return{
type:IS_LOADING_SKILLS,
payload:payload
}
}
    const isLoadingIntro = (payload)=>{
    return{
    type:IS_LOADING_INTRO,
    payload:payload
    }
}
```

state:

```
const InitialState ={
          loading:{
                 loadingIntro:false,
                 loadingSkills:false
                 },
           data:{
                 intro:"",
                 skills:[],
                }
             }
```

now when both loading state for each fetch data method become false the loading screen will disappear.
I want to know if this is a good approach or what is better please explain. thank you!

Comment: If you display intro and skill in different blocks, maybe you can display the loading image separately. And maybe you can try skeleton loading screens.

Comment: @oahehc no its a single page!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good approach, but your code has some weird parts. Either use async/await or .then/.catch callbacks (don't forget about the .catch, you could dispatch a setErrorMessage action or so).

So, with promises you would do:

```js
export const fetchSkills = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(isLoadingSkills(true));
    api.get(
      .then(({ data }) => {
        dispatch(setSkills(data)));
        dispatch(isLoadingSkills(false));
      })
      .catch((error) => ...stuff)
  }
}
export const fetchIntro = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(isLoadingIntro(true));
    api.get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        dispatch(setIntro(data)));
        dispatch(isLoadingIntro(false));
      })
      .catch((error) => ...stuff)
  }
}
```

And with async/await you would do:

```js
export const fetchSkills = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(isLoadingSkills(true));
      const { data } = await api.get(url)
      dispatch(setSkills(data)));
      dispatch(isLoadingSkills(false));
    } catch(error) {
      ...stuff
    }
  }
}
export const fetchIntro = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(isLoadingIntro(true));
      const { data } = await api.get(url)
      dispatch(setIntro(data)));
      dispatch(isLoadingIntro(false));
    } catch(error) {
      ...stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises. Instead of using .then and .catch on a promise you just define the function using await as async (which allows you to use await **AND** returns a promise), and you will need to try/catch to catch any errors that can happen whilst doing the request.